# Ssh communicator with paramiko

Tags: python, paramiko

I try to create a ssh class on Python.

```
ssh    = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(host, username=username, password=password)
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('ls -l')
ssh.close()
```

This code provides to connect server but when i try to connect another server, i have this error:

```
userauth is OK
transport._log() => Authentication type (publickey) not permitted.
transport._log() => Allowed methods: ['password']
transport._log() => EOF in transport thread
```

I couldn't resolve the error. any idea?